# Display accordion using Jquery Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a table full of data, upon clicking on any of the record. A jquery ajax function called and get the detailed information for that record and display it in the div associated with the record.

Now i want to show it in a accordion.

Most of time a jquery accordion works like this

```
   $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#accordion').accordion();  
});
```

But here i want that my div gets populated first with data then accordion method gets called. Because if accordion() called first then there is nothing for accordion to display as the request for data is still in processing.

My jquery ajax method is like this

```
 $(function () {
        $("span.Consignment").click(function () {
            var position = 'div#' + this.innerHTML;
            var url = "/Tracking/TrackingConsignment?consno=" + this.innerHTML;
            $(position).load(url, function() {
                $("a.Consignment").accordion();
                return false;
            });

        });
    });
```

This is my code

```
     @foreach (var lst in item.Item2)
        {
           <a href="#" class="Consignment">
                <table class="gridtable">
                    <a href="#">
                        <tr>
                            <td>                                   
                                <span class="Consignment" href="#">@lst.ConsignmentNo</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>@lst.ConsignmentDate
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </a>
                </table>
            </a>

            <div id="@lst.ConsignmentNo">
            </div>
        }
```

How should i make it work. First data then accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your accordion in the success of the `.load`.

```
.load(url,function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion();
})
```

Comment: This does not wok. I've updated my question with the full code. Kindly guide me where i am missing something.

Comment: ID's must be unique. change that to a classname and use `$(".accordion")...`

Comment: I don't get you. Will you please elaborate a little and give me some code. That'll be a great help.